# trying to use rename command but having issues

Tags: regex, bash, rename

I have several files like

`file01xyg.mkv  file02xyg.mkv  file03xyg.mkv  file04xyg.mkv  file05xyg.mkv  file06xyg.mkv`

and trying to rename them so they just say `01.mkv 02.mkv` etc

I've tried using the rename command by running:

`rename -n -e 's/file0[1-6]xyg.mkv/[1-6].mkv/' *.mkv`

But then I just get:

`(file01xyg.mkv, [1-6].mkv)`
`(file02xyg.mkv, [1-6].mkv)`
`(file03xyg.mkv, [1-6].mkv)`
`(file04xyg.mkv, [1-6].mkv)`
`(file05xyg.mkv, [1-6].mkv)`
`(file06xyg.mkv, [1-6].mkv)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The substitution command has the form `s/regex/replacement/`. The replacement is *not* a regex, therefore `[1-6]` inside the replacement is just a literal string.

Use a group `()` and reference the matched part inside the group using `\1`:

```
rename -n 's/file(0[1-6])xyg.mkv/\1.mkv/' *.mkv
```

Comment: Right so that worked, can you please explain what I was doing wrong and how this works?

Comment: So the replacement part can never be regex?

Comment: Yes. A regex in the replacement part wouldn't even make sense. Regexes are only for *reading* data, not writing. In your attempt `s/file0[1-6]xyg.mkv/[1-6].mkv/` a human might infer that the replacement `[1-6]` should be the same as the matched `[1-6]`, but for computers this isn't obvious at all. If the replacement regex did not look like the search pattern at all, even humans would scratch their head. What would you expect from the regex replacement `s/abc/.{7}/`? Should this  generate a random 7-character string?

Comment: Ah I see your point, is there somewhere I can learn more about this particular solution, the group and then matching it. is that part of the rename command or is that universal?

Comment: `rename` uses *perl compatible regular expressions* (PCRE) which are supported by many other tools (e.g. `grep -P`) and programming languages. You can search for keywords like "PCRE capturing group", but there isn't really much more to say than shown here.